# Proper custom writable (and readable) ModelSerializer field

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm working on a project that manages school staff. The relationship between the two is poorly implemented in my opinion so I am trying to refactor it. However, to minimize impact, since this is not a priority I'm trying to do this without breaking the front-end, which should be refactored at a later date. The current `Staff` model looks like this:

```
class Staff(models.Model):
    principal_at = models.ForeignKey(School, null=True)
    teacher_at = models.ForeignKey(School, null=True)
    # I'm only showing these two roles for the sake of simplicity but there are more.
```

I'm refactoring it to this:

```
class Staff(models.Model):
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        "principal",
        "teacher",
        # ...
    )
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)
    role = models.CharField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES)
    # ...

    @property
    def principal_at(self):
        return self.school if self.role == "principal" else None
    # ...
```

My `StaffSerializer` looks like this:

```
class StaffSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Staff
        fields = (
            "principal_at",
            "teacher_at",
            # ...
        )

    # There is also some custom validation to ensure the Staff can only have
    # one role.
```

If I just keep my it unchanged, the `principal_at` field becomes a `ReadOnlyField` and it doesn't get saved, which makes sense since my model attribute is now a property and not an actual writeable field. I changed, therefore, my serializer to this:

```
class StaffSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    kwargs = {"required": False, "queryset": School.objects.all()}

    principal_at = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(**kwargs)
    teacher_at = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(**kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Staff
        fields = (
            "principal_at",
            "teacher_at",
            # ...
        )

    def validate(self, data):
        principal_at = data.pop("principal_at", None)
        teacher_at = data.pop("teacher_at", None)
        # ...
        if principal_at:
            data.update(school_id=principal_at, role="principal")
        elif teacher_at:
            data.update(school_id=teacher_at, role="teacher")
        # ...
        return data
```

Now the model is saved correctly (I checked with ipdb) but in the process of building the response I get this:

```
TypeError: Object of type School is not JSON serializable
```

After this point I honestly don't remember what I've tried, but I've tried many things and nothing works.  One thing I do remember trying and that blew my mind was creating a custom field and overriding `to_representation`:

```
class RelatedSchoolSerializer(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        return value.pk

class StaffSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    kwargs = {"required": False, "queryset": School.objects.all()}

    principal_at = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(**kwargs)
    teacher_at = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(**kwargs)
    # ...
```

This kept failing with the same error, however, prompting me to add a breakpoint and check what the f**k is going on. Inside the debugger, to my absolute dismay, I got the following:

```
ipdb> value                                                                                                                                                                                
<rest_framework.relations.PKOnlyObject object at 0x7f9563c87f90>
ipdb> value.pk                                                                                                                                                                             
<School: School 0>
ipdb> value.pk.pk                                                                                                                                                                          
1
ipdb>
```

If I return `value.pk.pk` instead of `value.pk`, everything works. But even though my test suite is passing, I'm afraid that such a weird hack may have mysterious unintended consequences down the road. What on earth is going on? What is the proper way of doing this?